# Android Studio resource dialogue is not showing my project drawables

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I have encountered the following issue in Android Studio: when I select the `"..."` to specify the source drawable file for an ImageView, in the Project tab I don't see the project drawables, even if they do appear into the drawable folder on the left pane, but instead a long list of (I guess) system drawables (whose name is starting with `"abc_"`) and no trace of the custom files I have successfully pasted into the project drawable folders. 
If I try to write manually a reference to the correct resource in XML (`android:src="@drawable/main_title"`), I get the following error popup:
Rendering Problems Couldn't resolve resource `@drawable/main_title`. Failed to convert `@drawable/main_title` into a drawable.

Does anybody have any idea of what's happened? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put in `android:src` a string, not a Drawable. If you want to apply drawable to your `ImageView` src you should use somthing like this:

```
android:src="@drawable/your_image_drawable"
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm sorry but I typed incorrectly: I wrote "string" here but actually in Android Studio I wrote correctly "drawable". Now I corrected this post to see if someone can help. Thank you again.

Comment: @GabLab ok, so I assume that your drawable isn't a simple image, right? May be you could post its code here so we can check it?

Answer (score 0):

I just found my own mistake: I pasted the drawable files inside the drawable folder, while they must reside inside the res folder. Now it works.
Thanks for your replies.